# Longing context?

Tags: word-usage

Longing = a yearning desire.
But is that for something you never had or for thing you had but now are missing.

Comment: What do you need it for? What do you wish to express. Please provide a context. Your word can mean one or the other depending on the context.

Comment: For something i never had,

Comment: Do example sentences in dictionaries include such usages?

Answer (score 1):

> Longing for something I never had

is a perfectly valid phrase.

But this does not mean that *longing* cannot mean something that you did have before and lost:

> I long to see him again.